# Why NumPy is casting objects to floats?

Tags: python, class, numpy, intervals

I'm trying to store intervals (with its specific arithmetic) in NumPy arrays. If I use my own Interval class, it works, but my class is very poor and my Python knowledge limited.

I know [pyInterval](http://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and it's very complete. It covers my problems. The only thing which is not working is storing pyInterval objects in NumPy arrays.

```
class Interval(object):

    def __init__(self, lower, upper = None):
        if upper is None:
            self.upper = self.lower = lower
        elif lower <= upper:
            self.lower = lower
            self.upper = upper
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Lower is bigger than upper! {lower},{upper}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Interval " + str((self.lower,self.upper))

    def __mul__(self,another):
        values = (self.lower * another.lower,
                        self.upper * another.upper,
                        self.lower * another.upper,
                        self.upper * another.lower)
        return Interval(min(values), max(values))

import numpy as np
from interval import interval

i = np.array([Interval(2,3), Interval(-3,6)], dtype=object) # My class
ix = np.array([interval([2,3]), interval([-3,6])], dtype=object) # pyInterval
```

These are the results

```
In [30]: i
Out[30]: array([Interval (2, 3), Interval (-3, 6)], dtype=object)

In [31]: ix
Out[31]: 
array([[[2.0, 3.0]],

       [[-3.0, 6.0]]], dtype=object)
```

The intervals from pyInterval has been casted as list of list of floats. It doesn't be a problem if them preserves interval arithmetics...

```
In [33]: i[0] * i[1]
Out[33]: Interval (-9, 18)

In [34]: ix[0] * ix[1]
Out[34]: array([[-6.0, 18.0]], dtype=object)
```

`Out[33]` is the wished output. The output using pyInterval is incorrect. Obviously using raw pyInterval it works like a charm

```
In [35]: interval([2,3]) * interval([-3,6])
Out[35]: interval([-9.0, 18.0])
```

[Here](https://github.com/taschini/pyinterval/blob/master/interval/__init__.py) is the pyInterval source code. I don't understand why using this object NumPy doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: A quick guess is it inherits from tuple, and thus is an iterator.  `np.array` tries build the array from the elements of an iterable.  You can indirectly make an object array of iterables like lists or tuples..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, it is really hard for the `numpy.ndarray` constructor to infer what kind of data should go into it. It receives objects which resemble lists of tuples and makes do with it.

You can, however, help your constructor a bit by not having it guess the shape of your data:

```
a = interval([2,3])
b = interval([-3,6])
ll = [a,b]
ix = np.empty((len(ll),), dtype=object)
ix[:] = [*ll]
ix[0]*ix[1] #interval([-9.0, 18.0])
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPy sees each interval as an array of two numbers, and it does elementwise multiplication which you don't want.  Try this:

```
interval.__mul__(ix[0], ix[1])
```

That is a direct invocation of the function you want to call.  It should give you the answer  you need, even if it is not very pretty.  To turn it into something that works on whole arrays, you can do this:

```
itvmul = np.vectorize(interval.__mul__)
```

That will allow you to do elementwise multiplication of arrays of intervals: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html